# Keep sticky locked in a certain position after scrolling past X

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this sticky card and just need it to stay on hold in a certain position vertically when scrolling past a certain point. All i can do  right now is just change it's position to absolute and it will disappear from the current area when scrolling down.

```js
     $(window).scroll(function () {
            var distanceFromTop = $(document).scrollTop();
            if ($(window).width() > 991) {
                if (distanceFromTop < 2350) {
                    $('.sticky-card').css({ position: 'fixed' });
                }
                else {
                    $('.sticky-card').css({ position: 'absolute' });
                }
            }
            else {
                $('.sticky-card').css({ position: 'relative' });
            }
        });
```

```css
.sticky-card {
          position: fixed;
          width: 400px;
          max-width: 400px;
          z-index: 1000;
          top:15%;
          height:735px;
          background: rgb(149, 202, 228);
          background: -moz-linear-gradient(162deg, rgba(149,202,228,1) 0%, rgba(0,141,210,1) 52%, rgba(2,100,148,1) 100%);
          background: -webkit-linear-gradient(162deg, rgba(149,202,228,1) 0%, rgba(0,141,210,1) 52%, rgba(2,100,148,1) 100%);
          background: linear-gradient(162deg, rgba(149,202,228,1) 0%, rgba(0,141,210,1) 52%, rgba(2,100,148,1) 100%);
          filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#95cae4", endColorstr="#026494", GradientType=1);
          color: white;
          box-shadow: 5px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
          -webkit-box-shadow: 15px 15px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
          -moz-box-shadow: 15px 15px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
          box-shadow: 15px 15px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-md">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-8">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="text-left">
                                Some text on the left
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4">
                        <div class="sticky-card">
                            Some content here
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                
       </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I found a way to do this, I don't know if it's the best or not but it's the only
thing i could think of. This will keep the sticky stuck in that position after scrolling past it, once scroll back up it will be fixed and move with scroll again

```
.sticky-card.bottom{
  position: absolute;
  top: 1275px;
}

  $(window).scroll(function () {
        var distanceFromTop = $(document).scrollTop();
        if ($(window).width() > 1199) {
            if (distanceFromTop < 2200) {
                $('.sticky-card').addClass('fixed');
                $('.sticky-card').removeClass('bottom');

            }
            else {
                $('.sticky-card').removeClass('fixed');
                $('.sticky-card').addClass('bottom');
            }
        }
        else {
            $('.sticky-card').removeClass('fixed');
        }
    });
```